# How can we use sliderfield in aem 6.3 Touch ui?

Tags: aem, aem-touch-ui

Is there a way to use slider for blur and opacity options for an image in AEM 6.3?`maxValue="{Long}100"
minValue="{Long}0"
name="./background"`

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Nope. instead i used a number field. Is there a way we can do that? Please share some inputs.